# How to sum all the records and display as single in kanban view?

Tags: odoo

I need to sum the companies total and display as single row like in the image.

[image]

Now I just used the kanban view to display default view.

```xml
<kanban class="o_kanban_mobile">
    <field name="name"/>
    <field name="company"/>
    <field name="actual_amount"/>
    <field name="planned_amount"/>
    <templates>
        <t t-name="kanban-box">
            <div t-attf-class="oe_kanban_card oe_kanban_global_click">
                <table border="1" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="2"><t t-esc="record.name.value"/>-<t t-esc="record.company.value"/></td>
                        <td>Planned</td>
                        <td>Actual</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><t t-esc="record.planned_amount.value"/></td>
                        <td><t t-esc="record.actual_amount.value"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </t>
    </templates>
</kanban>
```

Comment: It would be much simpler to create a new model that aggregates your budget lines as a report. Would you be willing to go that route? I could outline what I would imagine it looking like in an answer.

Comment: I need this would be worked based on filter, any example on this?

Comment: is this a statistic view or user can create records from it.

Comment: It can be created by user...

Comment: How many record will be there and explain more what you want

Comment: For example There are two records are there in each company, The name is Gross and Net, Now I need to sum the Gross and Net values of all companies and display as a single value like shown in screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work for you.

Add a `char` field to your model don't show it . just define a defaut value for it,  `default = 'sum'` then groub by that field.

You should get the same result.